# Android: Showing a toast message when the checkbox is checked for the dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: android, object, checkbox, android-toast, ischecked

When an ImageButton is clicked a checkBox is created dynamically in my app.

The problem I'm facing is with toast messages not showing or **let's say the listener I am using for the checkboxes to show a toast message when the checkbox is checked is working only for the current/latest checkbox that has been created**. **Not for the checkboxes that had been created previously.**

**Problem,**
I saw that the problem could be with the variable (**toDoCheckBox**) I am using to save the newly created checkbox instance and every time it's getting overriding dynamically as I create newer checkboxes. So for the previous checkboxes, there is no reference pointing to them in order for the listener to work. (the problem could be this or not, i don't know for sure) **Even if this is the problem i don't know how to solve it**

**What i tried is that,**
creating the instance of checkbox on both onCreate as well as the createCheckBox method so that I could assign the listener in both the places.

1. on the onCreate()
2. on the createCheckbox()

**Only the latest created checkbox works and shows the toast messages**

**Can someone help me or guide me with the problem,

I want the toast message to show for every checkboxes**

**i posted only the code that could be of some use**

```
  private CheckBox toDoCheckBox; 
    private EditText defaultEditText;
    private List<CheckBox> listCheckBoxes;
    private int previousViewId = 0;

 @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.defaultEditText = findViewById(R.id.defaultEditText);
    toDoCheckBox = new CheckBox(this);
    this.listCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<>();

    this.checkBoxListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if(toDoCheckBox.isChecked()){
                toDoCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You did a good work, keep it up!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
    toDoCheckBox.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
}


public void createCheckBox() {

    //CREATING A CHECKBOX
    toDoCheckBox = new CheckBox(this);
    toDoCheckBox.setText(defaultEditText.getText().toString());
    toDoCheckBox.setTextSize(20);
    toDoCheckBox.setId(View.generateViewId());

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) defaultEditText.getLayoutParams();

    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams newParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    newParams.width = params.width;
    newParams.height = params.height;

    //Constraints
    newParams.startToStart = params.startToStart;
    newParams.endToEnd = params.endToEnd;
    newParams.topToTop = params.topToTop;
    newParams.topToBottom = params.topToBottom;

    //Margins
    newParams.leftMargin = params.leftMargin;
    newParams.topMargin = params.topMargin;
    newParams.bottomMargin = params.bottomMargin;
    newParams.rightMargin = params.rightMargin;

    constraintLayout.addView(toDoCheckBox, -1, newParams);
    previousViewId = toDoCheckBox.getId();
    defaultEditText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    createEditText();
    toDoCheckBox.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    this.listCheckBoxes.add(toDoCheckBox);
    totalCheckBox++;

}
```

Comment: still waiting for an answer

Comment: why arent you using recyclerview ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the local checkbox object instead of the global `toDoCheckBox`.